# Excel 2007 VBA - create chart via calculated data

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Just starting out with this VBA stuff....

From all the examples I see, the data for charts is based on a range of Cells as seen here :

```
Sub UpdateChartSourceData()
  With ActiveSheet
    .ChartObjects(1).Chart.SetSourceData _
        Source:=.Range("ChtSourceData"), _
        PlotBy:=xlColumns
  End With
End Sub
```

My routine is calculating a few values internally via subroutines and storing the values in variables and not cells on the sheet.

It is these variables that I would like to use as the data for a chart, but have been unable to figure out how to set the Source to be variables from my Subroutine instead of a range of cells.

Do you have a link to any examples?

Comment: You can create a temporary sheet and insert your values there, activate the chart with that range

Comment: If the data is stored in an array (but you are storing in multiple variables in your case - so not sure how helpful it would be) then you could use something like this [assign series value using Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.series.values).

Comment: One main objective is to try and avoid "hidden" sheets/cells.

Comment: I tried using :
Charts.Add

ActiveChart.ChartType = xl3DColumn
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
 Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19)  but that produced an error. It appears I will have to research some basic chart creation stuff first.

Comment: Have posted a simple macro (tested) in the answers, doesn't solve all your problem but you can take it as an example and try to work it out.

Comment: You got an error because `Charts.Add` gave you a chart with no series. Try `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19)`. Also use 2D charts, like type `xlColumnClustered`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is not an answer to your question but you can take it as an example and try to work it out.

```
Dim array_value(1 To 10) As Integer
Dim excel_Chart As ChartObject

'Inserting test data - but in your case it has to be done differently
For i = 1 To 10
    array_value(i) = i
Next i

Set excel_Chart = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(50, 40, 200, 100)

With excel_Chart.Chart
    .ChartType = xl3DColumn
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = array_value
End With
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Huge help, as I needed a place to start with Charts thanks.